# Separate signed int into bytes in NXC

Tags: nxt, nxc

Is there any way to convert a signed integer into an array of bytes in NXC? I can't use explicit type casting or pointers either, due to language limitations.

I've tried:

```
for(unsigned long i = 1; i <= 2; i++)
{
    MM_mem[id.idx] = ((val & (0xFF << ((2 - i) * 8)))) >> ((2 - i) * 8));

    id.idx++;
}
```

<s>But it fails.</s>

**EDIT:** This works... It just wasn't downloading. I've wasted about an hour trying to figure it out. >_>

---

**EDIT:** In NXC, `>>` is a arithmetic shift. `int` is a signed 16-bit integer type. A `byte` is the same thing as `unsigned char`.

---

NXC is ['Not eXactly C'](http://bricxcc.sourceforge.net/nbc/), a relative of C, but distinctly different from C.

Comment: I don't suppose anyone will add the tag `nxc`? :)

Comment: Created the [nxc] tag for you, removed the inaccurate [c] tag.

Comment: What is `nxc`, and why is it more appropriate than the original tag `c`?  Google to the rescue: `nxc` is 'Not eXactly C': see http://bricxcc.sourceforge.net/nbc/ etc.

Comment: @Jonathan It's a ["unofficial"] language for the LEGO Mindstorms NXT. It stands for `Not eXactly C`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this in NXC with the opcodes available in the underlying VM is to use FlattenVar to convert any type into a string (aka byte array with a null added at the end).  It results in a single VM opcode operation where any of the above options which use shifts and logical ANDs and array operations will require dozens of lines of assembly language.

```
task main()
{
  int x = Random(); // 16 bit random number - could be negative
  string data;
  data = FlattenVar(x); // convert type to byte array with trailing null
  NumOut(0, LCD_LINE1, x);
  for (int i=0; i < ArrayLen(data)-1; i++)
  {
#ifdef __ENHANCED_FIRMWARE
    TextOut(0, LCD_LINE2-8*i, FormatNum("0x%2.2x", data[i]));
#else
    NumOut(0, LCD_LINE2-8*i, data[i]);
#endif
  }
  Wait(SEC_4);
}
```

The best way to get help with LEGO MINDSTORMS and the NXT and Not eXactly C is via the mindboards forums at http://forums.mindboards.net/

Answer (score 4):

How about

```
    unsigned char b[4];

    b[0] = (x & 0xFF000000) >> 24;
    b[1] = (x & 0x00FF0000) >> 16;
    b[2] = (x & 0x0000FF00) >> 8;
    b[3] = x & 0xFF;
```

Comment: You're assuming the target architecture has a 32-bit long type.

Comment: @djs I am assuming nothing. He didn't specify it so I showed one possibility. From this he can surely adapt it to his word size / byte order.

Comment: @cnicutar For all we know his problem is that he thinks it is 32-bit. That said, I don't think we've established that he's asking about C yet, either.

Comment: @djs I am sure the concepts of masking & shifting are general enough.

Comment: Oh wait... *someone* had unplugged the USB, so it wasn't downloading. It's working, and I'll accept this soon.

Answer (score 2):

*Question originally tagged [c](/questions/tagged/c); this answer may not be applicable to Not eXactly C.*

What is the problem with this:

```
int value;
char bytes[sizeof(int)];

bytes[0] = (value >>  0) & 0xFF;
bytes[1] = (value >>  8) & 0xFF;
bytes[2] = (value >> 16) & 0xFF;
bytes[3] = (value >> 24) & 0xFF;
```

You can regard it as an unrolled loop.  The shift by zero could be omitted; the optimizer would certainly do so.  Even though the result of right-shifting a negative value is not defined, there is no problem because this code only accesses the bits where the behaviour is defined.

This code gives the bytes in a little-endian order - the least-significant byte is in `bytes[0]`.  Clearly, big-endian order is achieved by:

```
int value;
char bytes[sizeof(int)];

bytes[3] = (value >>  0) & 0xFF;
bytes[2] = (value >>  8) & 0xFF;
bytes[1] = (value >> 16) & 0xFF;
bytes[0] = (value >> 24) & 0xFF;
```

Comment: To be completely pedantic (if we're talking about C), there are no "bits where the behavior is defined" (§6.5.7 in C1x, but the same text appears in C99): "If [the left operand] has a signed type and a negative value, *the resulting value is implementation-defined*."  That said, the question seems to be about some other language altogether.

Comment: @Stephen: yes, though the underlying issue is usually whether an arithmetic or a logical shift is employed at the CPU (assembly) level, and the difference is whether the sign bit or a zero bit is propagated; but the result is that the high-order bits are all zeroes or all ones (and it is implementation defined - not undefined or unspecified - which it is).  But, the code shown does not access the high-order bits.  Nevertheless, you are technically correct - the standard does not say what will happen, but it does require the implementation to document what will happen.

Comment: absolutely; I'm merely pointing out that the implementation could document that right-shift of a negative value can produce a trap representation, or return bits from `/dev/random`, or do any number of other things, and still be within the standard.  However, as the question doesn't actually seem to be about the C language, this is rather besides the point.

Comment: Nope, NXC uses [a bizarre form of :)] arithmetic shifts, and this doesn't work.

Comment: @muntoo: the NXC manual doesn't indicate that there's anything bizarre about the shift operators - the only somewhat unusual feature is that the `int` type is 16 bits rather than 32 as assumed above, and that's only unusual in the world of desktop computing; in the world of embedded computing in hardware where NXC is used, I suspect 16-bit `int` is still fairly common.  The NXC manual is not self-contained; it doesn't cover a lot of the finer details of the language behaviour.